# Getting NullPointerException : I am trying read value defined in jsp file SendSms.jsp in SmsServlet file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception

I am trying read value defined in jsp file SendSms.jsp in SmsServlet. I am getting below error. If I run without request.getParameter() it will work. Below is the error am getting

type Exception report

message

> description The server encountered an
>   internal error () that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:336)
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.getParameterValues(Parameters.java:192)
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.getParameter(Parameters.java:237)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1000)
org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:352)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorRequestWrapper.getParameter(MonitorRequestWrapper.java:182)
SmsServlet.processRequest(SmsServlet.java:31)
SmsServlet.doGet(SmsServlet.java:160)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:368)
```

Thanks.

My JSP Code..

```
<form action="SmsServlet" method="get">
            Mobile No. : <input type ="text" name="phone"/><br><br>
            Message : <textarea name="msg" rows="5"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
        </form>
```

My Servlet code..

```
        String phone = null;
        String msg = null;
        phone = request.getParameter(phone);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

```
request.getParameter()
```

returns `null`

It means your request doesn't contain the param you are trying to read. probably issue with html id/name double check it

Comment: No i declared it as <input type ="text" name="phone"/> in jsp. and calling it in servlet as String phone = request.getParameter(phone); Am passing parameter value in get method. I can see value passed in address bar.

Comment: It should be `request.getParameter("phone");` and what is the url  look like. ?

Comment: URL looks like: http://localhost:8084/WebApplication/SmsServlet?phone=9844633879&msg=hi

Comment: You must get `request.getParameter("phone");` not null in `doGet()` re check for it.

Comment: Thanks to all.. I was not added the double qoutes in getParameter() method.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that you are passing a null name to getParameter